# Compound statement to change value after returning it?

Tags: c, return

Im wondering if it is possible to have a variable changed after returning its value?

The function in question is a simple get function for a private Boolean flag variable. I would like reads of this flag to be destructive, so I thought:

```
bool myGet (context_t * someContext) {
    return (someContext->flag) ? (someContext->flag = false) : false;
}
```

Reasoning that the result of evaluating the statement `(someContext->flag = false)`would be `true`, but it appears not.

Maybe it's evaluated *before* the condition `(someContext->flag)?`.

Is there any other way to achieve the intended functionality without resorting to temporarily storing the flag value, clearing the flag and then returning the temporary copy? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the argument to `return` must be evaluated before the `return` itself is evaluated, i.e. before execution leaves the current function.

The value of an assignment is the assigned value, so it's `false` as you experienced.

I think the closest you can come is with post-increment, but that will of course strictly limit the values available.

There's *nothing wrong* with doing it the explicit way:

```
bool getAndClear(context_t *someContext)
{
  if(someContext->flag)
  {
    someContext->flag = false;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

it's very clear and *way* easier to understand than your scary code. It's easy to imagine that it's possible for compiler to optimize it, since it's pretty straight-forward.

If I wanted to get clever, I'd probably use something like:

```
bool getAndClear2(context_t *someContext)
{
  const bool flag = someContext->flag;

  someContext->flag ^= flag; /* Clears if set, leaves alone if not set. */

  return flag;
}
```

Note that it doesn't branch, which is sometimes nifty. But, again, being clever is not always the most awesome path to take.

Also note that I consider it a requirement that this function isn't just named "get" something, since it doesn't take a `const` pointer that would be an instant warning flag in my head. Since it has super-strange (for a getter) side-effects, that should be reflected in the name somehow.

Comment: I like this got away without needing the temporary variable and has same number of branch

Answer (score 2):

> Reasoning that the result of evaluating the statement `(someContext->flag = false)` would be true, but it appears not.

`(someContext->flag = false)` is an assignment expression. Its value is the value of the expression being assigned (i.e. `false`).

The assignment does go through, although it happens before the return, not after it. If you want to be fancy and stay with the ternary operator, you can use comma operator, like this:

```
return (someContext->flag) ? (someContext->flag = false, true) : false;
```

This is not very readable, though, so I would prefer this equivalent implementation, which has no conditionals:

```
bool temp = someContext->flag;
someContext->flag = false;
return temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `(someContext->flag = false)` it set `someContext->flag` to false, then return it.

You could do :

```
return (someContext->flag) ? !(someContext->flag = false) : false;
```

This way you will return the oposite of `someContext->flag` that you just set to false (so you return true) but `someContext->flag` will stay false after the return

**EDIT**

the most unreadable would be :

```
return !(someContext->flag = !someContext->flag);
```

Comment: I like this method, short and sweet :) 
Does lack some readability however, so I may have to go with unwind's answer

Comment: You just finish by getting used to it but I admit. It could even be worst ! (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the post-decrement operator:

```
return (someContext->flag) ? someContext->flag-- : false;
```

This will only have the desired result if the `true` value for your flag has the numeric value `1`.